# Terraform 0.13 - when working with count on modules, is there a way to ensure resources are deleted before recreation?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm running into a issue where resources are destroyed and recreated when using the count functionality on modules. Now I'm fine with this if that's how it has to work but the annoying part is that when `terraform apply` is run, the deletion and recreation appear to happen at the same time resulting in the 409 error down below. Running `terraform apply` a second time will always succeed.

Is there anyway to avoid this situation where deletion / creation are attempted at the same time or even ensure the deletion of resources occurs first?

```
module "service" {
  count  = length(var.names_map)

  source = "../../modules/service"

  name   = var.names_map[count.index].name                 
  // other variables
}
```

module service looks like this

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name               = "${var.name}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_assume_role_policy_document.json
}
```

error when initially running `terraform apply`, reruns will succeed though

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role **************-*******: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name **************-******* already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: ea2a4beb-5ee1-46ff-9e16-4a3c11fb9cfa

  on ../../modules/service/main.tf line 147, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role":
 147: resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
```

Comment: I think there is not. `lifecycle` doesn't work with modules. But why do you create and re-create the same resources all the time?

Comment: I don't want to but that appears to be how using count on modules works. I suspect because it is list who's length can change that terraform doesn't know how to manage them deterministically

Comment: This is not how `count` on modules works. It sounds like something else is going on here and perhaps a different question to ask here would be "why doesn't this configuration converge?" (but to answer that would require seeing the proposed plan and all of the declarations of the other variables/resources shown in the configuration here)

Comment: So I am seeing this happen when the count changes and not when the count is the same. My current guess is the order of the list matters. Potentially only appending new items to the end of `names_map` on created at will stabilize terraform's resource management or worst case any change in size of the list triggers a full destroy recreate